# How to determine Watch Orientation (i.e. is the Digital Crown on the right or the left?)

Tags: watchos

I wanted to know how to determine whether the Digital Crown is at the upper right or the lower left.
Since I found the solution I wanted to let others know as well. See answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if WKInterfaceDevice.current().crownOrientation == .right {
    ()
} else {
    ()
}
```